# Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewCell'

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

```
   let bubbleView : UIView = {

    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = blueColor
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return view
}()


let messageImageView : UIImageView = {

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return imageView

}()
init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

// getting error in like "super.init(frame: frame)" as Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewCell'please help me in sorting this problem thanks in advance...

Answer (score 21):

I guess the code that you provided is from `UITableViewCell` type class. So in the initializer you should call designed initializer for this class. Not from `UIView`

The designated initializer for `UITableViewCell` class is

`init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)`

So in you class you should override this initializers:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From the docs for `init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)`:

> This method is the designated initializer for the class.

The `super` initializer you're calling is for `UIView`, not `UITableViewCell`.